# Zoom Plaine Object in Android (GLES20)

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a plaine object which have an image. I want to implementing Zoom in\out this object.

I try use

```
Matrix.setScaleM(...)
```

and it works, but it just increases the image in the middle instead of gradually come to the place that I need. At this point I want to make something like a gallery, on each phone it is - open Gallery on your phone and see - when you try to zoom in image - viewport gradually moved to zoomed viewport. So how can i do that?

Comment: You should translate the matrix before scaling it. Or translate after scaling. Of course to the right position calculated by you.

Comment: I know about this. But what the translation value coef i neen to set?